# Adobe Flash Builder: How to make a SWF with a progress bar for loading itself?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I have an AS3 project that has all its assets embedded using the `[Embed]` metadata tag because I would like the resulting SWF to be completely self-contained for the sake of portability on the internet.

**Problem:** 
The file size is rather large, and I would like a progress bar to be displayed as it loads itself instead of a blank screen until it's completely finished. I can already achieve this with Adobe Animate (Flash Professional) by having a **timeline** with a light frame 1 and a heavy frame 2 which has a MovieClip that embeds the bulk of the assets.

I'm trying to switch over to Adobe Flash Builder, which has no IDE timeline, but I'm at a loss on how to do the same thing as the Flash IDE. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [solution that works with ASC2 / AIR SDK](http://web.archive.org/web/20180913205035/http://fortheloss.org/how-to-preloader-in-flash-builder-4-7/). Although his example preloader extends Sprite, and I believe you need to extend MovieClip to make it work, since you need a frame 2. And you need a gotoAndStop(2) once it has finished loading itself. Additional information [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20141213055741/https://forums.adobe.com/message/4695625). Man, it's not a good sign when all your reference links go through web.archive.org!

Answer (score 4):

**Option №1**. The one I'd picked, because it's easier to comprehend: external loader. A lightweight **SWF** with the only purpose of displaying some preloading info like % or progress while loading the heavyweight main module.

**Option №2**. There's a certain *metatag* that allows you to emulate that frame 1 preloader behavior. Keep in mind that is is not supported by **ASC2.0** compiler (**AIR SDK**, I assume) but only by **ASC1.0** compiler (**Flex SDK**). **Flash Builder** is a descendant of **Flex Builder**, so it's fine, I guess, but if it does not work for you, the first thing you should check is the compiler version your **Flash Builder** is packed with.

So, your main (the one you set as the document class in the settings) class should have that one *metatag*:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    
    // Brace for the magic impact.
    [Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            // This is important, because at the moment of creation
            // the instance is not attached to the stage.
            if (stage) onStage(null);
            else addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
        }
        
        private function onStage(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(flash.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
            
            // This is the entry point of your actual application.
            // The rest of the class goes normally from this point on.
```

Then, the mentioned preloader class. Its name should qualify exactly as mentioned in the *metatag* above.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    
    import flash.events.Event;
    
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
    
    // This class represents the multi-framed main timeline
    // thus it should subclass the basic MovieClip.
    public class Preloader extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Preloader()
        {
            // Subscribe to all necessary points to monitor the loading.
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
            
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        }
        
        private function ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            // Handle loading errors here.
        }
        
        private function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            // Display loading progress here.
            // Use e.bytesLoaded and e.bytesTotal values
            // to calculate the % loaded and the overall loading progress.
        }
        
        private function onFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            // When the loading is finished, the main timeline,
            // represented by Preloader class moves to the frame 2.
            if (currentFrame == totalFrames)
            {
                stop();
                
                onComplete();
            }
        }
        
        // This method concludes the loading,
        // cleans up the preloader itself
        // and instantiates the Main class.
        private function onComplete():void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
            
            loaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);
            loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
            
            // So, here's the thing. You don't import the Main class
            // because if you import it, then it will be embedded into
            // the Preloader, then it must be loaded before Preloader
            // can be initialized, which kind of fails the whole idea.
            
            // Thus, you don't import the Main class but obtain it
            // via the other means, like the "getDefinitionByName" method.
            // Again, the fully qualified class name is to be provided.
            
            var aMain:Class = getDefinitionByName("Main") as Class;
            stage.addChild(new aMain as DisplayObject);
            
            // Remove this instance as it no longer needed for anything.
            parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
```